# Splitting values in index of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe of this type:

```
d = {'a': [100,150,180,190]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[(2010,1) ,(2010,2 ), (2011,1) ,(2011,2 )])
```

Which returns

```
Out[91]: 
             a
(2010, 1)  100
(2010, 2)  150
(2011, 1)  180
(2011, 2)  190
```

My scope is to split the values in the index and make the dataframe more readable by preserving the information of the index. In other words, my expected outcome is this:

```
dd = {'a': [100,150,180,190], 'year': [2010, 2011, 2010,2011], 'class': [1,2, 1,2]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dd)

Out[92]: 
     a  year  class
0  100  2010      1
1  150  2011      2
2  180  2010      1
3  190  2011      2
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select each value of tuples by indexing and last create default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df['year'] = df.index.str[0]
df['class'] = df.index.str[1]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     a  year  class
0  100  2010      1
1  150  2010      2
2  180  2011      1
3  190  2011      2
```

Another idea is create new `DataFrame` and join to original:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.index.tolist(), columns=['year','class'], index=df.index)
df = df.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     a  year  class
0  100  2010      1
1  150  2010      2
2  180  2011      1
3  190  2011      2
```

Another idea is create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['year','class'])
print (df)
              a
year class     
2010 1      100
     2      150
2011 1      180
     2      190
```

And then possible create columns:

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   year  class    a
0  2010      1  100
1  2010      2  150
2  2011      1  180
3  2011      2  190
```